# The purpose of the detailed counting of Benei Yisrael in the Torah

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, number, bamidbar-parsha

We know that all letter in the Torah has a purpose. A lot of laws are learned from a little thing in the Torah, etc.

What is the purpose of all the details in the counting of Benei Yisrael in Parashat Bemidbar?

For example, why the number of Yehuda tribe is repeated in (2,4)?

The idea of the importance of counting, showing the חשיבות of every Yehudi, is known. But why all the details, especially when repeated?
Kind of יפה *מנינם של* אבות מתורתם של בנים ?... Sure there is something else...

Comment: Have a chapter on this, if you're interested: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mqQbnapp-xqqFZ3ePtXdPMbLeeaAp5NB/view Parshas Bamidbar, p. 209 I'd like to know what you think of it!

Answer (score 1):

The repeating of the counts in Bamidbar chapter 2 is to reiterate the counts in the context of their arrangement as a camp around the mishkan.
It gives the whole event much festivity and pomp and circumstance. 
The master plan of the universe is finally being realized: God's nation has been redeemed, given the Torah and built the mishkan at it's center. Now all that need to be done is that they march on and enter the promised land...

Answer (score 0):

From [my answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30047/why-is-every-commandment-and-action-in-regards-to-the-10-plagues-repeated/90479#90479) to a similar type of question:

> [Ralbag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gersonides) notes (at the end of his commentary on Parshas Pekudei) that
>   there is a troubling problem that the Torah is often repetitive,
>   though being perfect it should not contain needless repetition. He
>   writes that "until today" he has not found a satisfactory explanation
>   for this tendency. However, he does offer two suggestions to explain
>   the general tendency (apart from any reasons that can explain a
>   specific instance of repetition).
>
> 1) That was the way people talked then, so the Torah spoke this way as
>   well.
>
> 2) The Torah is often very brief on very deep matters. The reader
>   might think this is because the Torah is generally very brief and it
>   is not because there is something very deep that needs to be extracted
>   from the text. Therefore, the Torah is very lengthy in other places to
>   show the reader that any brevity is not simply because the Torah is
>   always brief; rather, it is because of the depth of the specific
>   discussion, and the reader should know that he must delve into it to
>   properly understand it.
>
> > וראוי שנעיין בהתרת ספק עמוק יקרה בזה הסיפור וברבים מסיפורי התורה וזה
> >     שהוא ראוי בתורה מצד שלמותה שלא יהיה בדבריה כפל ומוֹתר ואנחנו רואים בזה
> >     המקום הכפל ידמה שיהיה לבלתי צורך כי היה די בשיאמר ויעש בצלאל בן אורי
> >     בן חור את כל מלאכת המשכן כאשר צוה ה' את משה ואתו אהליאב בן אחיסמך וגו'
> >     וכבר מצאנו כמו זה ההכפל במקומות רבים מן התורה ולא מצאנו עד היום בזה
> >     סיבה כוללת מספקת ואפשר שנאמר שכבר היה מנהג האנשים ההם בזמן מתן תורה
> >     שיהיו סיפוריהם בזה האופן והנביא ידבר לפי מנהגו או נאמר כי מפני שקיצרה
> >     התורה במקומות העמוקים האריכה זה האריכות במקומות האחרים אשר האריכות בהם
> >     בלתי מזיק כדי שלא נחשוב כי הקיצור היה במקומות ההם לפי שמנהג התורה הוא
> >     לדבר בקיצור וזה שכבר נראה ממנהגה לדבר באריכות וזה ממה שיביאנו לבקש
> >     הסיבה מפני מה קיצרה התורה במקומות ההם ונעמוד מפני זה על טבע הנושא אשר
> >     בו הדברים ההם כי הוא הסיבה בקיצור ההוא ונעמוד מפני זה על כונת התורה
> >     באותם הדברים הקצרים כשנעיין בהם בכל הצדדין שאפשר לעמוד מהם על כונותיהם